# cocos2d-x create dynamic shapes with labels on them and text boxes

Tags: cocos2d-x

What will be the best approach to create draggable and movable dynamic shapes
that contains labels and edit text widgets on them .
i attached images to show what shapes i mean and more different shapes are planed  [image]

Comment: How do you define "best"? What requirements do you have? Do you know how to design the nodes to make them look like this (in which case the question is too broad and subjective) or is just finding any way to achieve this actually the core of your question?

Comment: i have no idea what is "best" , i need to have some factory class that will create different shapes based on parameters . 
now the shapes as you see are some kind of closed polygons

Comment: What step of the process you are having problems with? Are you maybe just looking for a way to generate the physics shapes from these images? (answers for that on SO)

Comment: Hey,well from what i saw in other application like :Scratch (programming blocks ) or snap!  the Shapes are generated dynamically that is drawn to the screen using svg or other method for dynamically drawing shapes . my question is basically  simple . how to draw dynamically shapes in cococs2d-x but with widgets on top of them